# Audio analysis Implementation

Tags: signal-analysis

I am supposed to implement some analyses for the customer including NB, WB, Time Domain etc. This is in the audio signal processing domain. The scope of work also includes "Audio Analysis". Can anybody throw more light on this? Nothing much available in public domain. Is it STFT??

Thanks and regards
VV

Comment: What's NB and WB ?

Comment: Oh boy.  "Audio Analysis" can be very broad, can you get more specific about the requirements?  I disagree, there is tons available online, but you need to know what you are looking for.

Comment: NB is Narrow band, WB is Wide band. The requirement is also generic, only "audio analysis"